# How to access nested Json objects in Kotlin through Wordpress REST API?

Tags: wordpress, kotlin

I am building an app using Kotlin for my WordPress blog,
I want to access nested JSON object values from my WordPress blog,
I can access the root id, userid.

Say I want to access the Title, that is inside rendered.

**JSON**

```
"id": 1826,
"date": "2022-04-18T15:02:49",
"date_gmt": "2022-04-18T15:02:49",
"guid": {
"rendered": "https://example.com/?p=1826"
},
"modified": "2022-04-18T15:02:51",
"modified_gmt": "2022-04-18T15:02:51",
"slug": "to-android-heres-how",
"status": "publish",
"type": "post",
"link": "https://example.com/news/to-android-heres-how/",
"title": {
"rendered": "To Android: Here&#8217;s How"
},
```

**Here is my data class**

package com.example.retrofitexample.dataclass

```
data class blogdata(
    val id: Int,
    val author: Int,
    val categories: List<Int>,
    val comment_status: String,
    val content: String,
    val date: String,
    val date_gmt: String,
    val excerpt: String,
.....
    val modified_gmt: String,
    val ping_status: String,
    val slug: String,
    val status: String,
    val sticky: Boolean,
    val template: String,
    val title: String,
  )
```

ActivityFile . kt

```
  private fun getMyData() {
                val retrofitBuilder = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .build()
                    .create(APIinterface::class.java)

                val retrofitData = retrofitBuilder.getData()

                with(retrofitData) {

                    enqueue(object : Callback<List<blogdata>?> {
                        override fun onResponse(
                            call: Call<List<blogdata>?>,
                            response: Response<List<blogdata>?>
                        ) {
                           val myStringBilder = StringBuilder()
                          for (myData in responseBody) {
                               myStringBilder.append(myData.id)
                               myStringBilder.append("\n")
                          }

                            val txtID = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.userId)
                         txtID.text = myStringBilder

                        }


                        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<blogdata>?>, t: Throwable) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure:" + t.message)
                        }
```

I am able to access the parent object details but not the nested ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the `title` is not a type of `string`

```
"title": {
    "rendered": "To Android: Here&#8217;s How"
}
```

To access nested data, you've to make a `data class` for the nested data itself and then you can assign that `variable` to be a type of this defined `data class`

Create a `data class` named `Title` (this name could be anything)

```
data class Title (
    val rendered: String
    )
```

Inside parent `data class` assign `title` to be a of type `Title`

```
data class blogdata(
    val id: Int,
    val author: Int,
    val categories: List<Int>,
    val comment_status: String,
    val content: String,
    val date: String,
    val date_gmt: String,
    val excerpt: String,
.....
    val modified_gmt: String,
    val ping_status: String,
    val slug: String,
    val status: String,
    val sticky: Boolean,
    val template: String,
    val title: Title,
  )
```

---

As you are using `GsonConverter` you may want to give different names to the variables of `data class` than the one defined in the `Json`, as `Kotlin` follows `camelCase` while `Json` follows `snake_case`, you can use `@SerializedName` to give a different name to the variable than their `Json` counterpart.

Like for `comment_status`, you can do this

```
@SerializedName("comment_status")
val commentStatus: String
```

Comment: Thank you so much for making my life easier, watched so many tutorials could not find answer to this simple issue. Thank you for your help :)